# How to wake or terminate a sleeping std::thread gracefully?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, cross-platform, portability

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std:

void f()
{
    // Sleeping for a very long while
    while (SOCKET s = accept(listening_socket, ...))
    {
         // ...
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(f);
    DoSomething();
    t.???(); /* What to place here to wake/terminate thread f? */
}
```

Under Win32, I can use `TerminateThread()` to kill a thread. But what I want is a cross-platform method to do that.

How should I do that gracefully in C++?

Comment: One rule in designing multithreaded apps: "Never kill a thread, just let them commit suicide."

Comment: Why do you want it to sleep for so long time from first step?

Comment: Do a timed wait on a condition variable that `main` has a reference to instead of a sleep, and if the condition triggers then return.

Comment: @billz, the thread is listening to new connections. I've updated the original post.

Comment: Set some 'terminate' flag, then temporarily open a local connection to make the accept() return.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend sleeping on a broadcast signal, semaphore, condition variable, or something instead of doing a blocking sleep.  Then your application just sets the signal and anyone that is *sleeping* will wake up and can exit.  It is a much cleaner solution since it gives the thread body a chance to cleanup whatever it might be doing - including releasing locks!

*Response to Update*
In this specific case, call `select` with a timeout before you call `accept`.

Comment: I've updated the example code in the original post. The thread can't wait on a given event object, because it is blocked inside a system-provided function.

Answer (score 4):

The first issue comes from blocking mode socket accept, you should use non-blocking socket mode.

You can set a flag in while loop, for example:

```
struct AcceptHandler
{
  AcceptHandler()
  : is_terminated(false)
  {
  }

  void accept()
  {
    while(!is_terminated)
    {
       // select
       // accept
      cout << " in loop " << endl;
    }
  }

  void terminate()
  {
    is_terminated = true;
  }

private:
  std::atomic<bool> is_terminated;
};

int main()
{
  AcceptHandler ah;
  std::thread t(std::bind(&AcceptHandler::accept, std::ref(ah)));
  t.join(); /// this is just demo, it blocks here

  ah.terminate();

  return 0;
}
```

I used a flag(is_terminated) in the sample you could use condition variable(preferred way).

Comment: Note as written this has a data race on `is_terminated`.

Comment: @GManNickG please give more details? you mean join and terminate?

Comment: If a variable as written to at the same time any other thread is reading it (or writing it), it's a data race. Here `is_terminated` can be written to (`is_terminated = true`) at the same time it is read (`while (!is_terminated)`). It needs to be `std::atomic<bool>` (or protected with a mutex, but that's overkill).